# Processing large amount of user data from spreadsheet both inserts and updates .net & SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

We are adding some new functions to an existing C# .net web app where we will be grabbing a pipe delimited file on a weekly basis containing user related data from another system. We will need to process this file of 3,000+ rows (with potential for more) and determine if we need to insert a new user record or update an existing. Along with the user record there is other affected tables where find or creates are required such as what role, location, and group the user belongs to.

The path we currently went down was to use SQL Server cursors but after doing some reading it seems like the community is pretty down on them. I thought about just writing this all in code with linq but I'm not sure if that is a better approach or worth the update. So what is the most efficient way to handle all of that data with both updates and creates required and having to deal with related tables. I also need to mark each row that we process in the staging table with a boolean flag of processed and failed.

I don't necessarily expect this process to run in just a few seconds but I haven't been able to find a solid answer on the best approach to handle this large amount of data.

Comment: This is pretty broad but you are right, cursors are not a good way to handle data. If you do this in linq you are just moving the cursor from the database to your application which will be even slower. You could look at using MERGE. Or simply do an update with output so you can mark those that were updated. Then do an insert for the rest.

Comment: Sounds like a job for SSIS or Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was afraid of, that doing it in code wouldn't be helping it all once it actually translated it to the sql.

Comment: 3K rows is no data at all. An Excel file with 3K rows isn't big either - Excel files can have up to 1M rows per sheet. Importing Excel files into SQL Server is very easy, already available as the `Import Data` wizard in SSMS. That wizard generates an SSIS package that can be saved and executed over and over

Comment: The *efficient* way is to create an SSIS package with the transformations you want to perform. The typical process is to load the data, process it and save it in a staging table. Once there you can left join it with the target table in an `UPDATE` statement that will update the existing records, followed by an `INSERT` that will insert the new records